# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

my route code

```
 return View::make('test')->with('foo', foo::all()->with('foos', 'bars'));
```

why this is throwing this exception?

Comment: Class Collection does not have method `with` http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html `foo::all()` returns Collection (all entities, like an array), as I understand, not a query Builder instance http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html

Comment: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with

Comment: Yes, there is a `with` method, which is a method of Builder class, not a method of Collection class. Collection (obtained by `all()`) is a result of the executed query, containing all data from database, not a query that should request it.

Answer (score 11):

The function `all()` executes the query so you get a collection. You have to call `with` on a query builder instance. Meaning you should do this:

```
foo::with('foos', 'bars')->get();
```

Also, classes start with a capital letter by convention so it should be `Foo` ;)