# Laravel Eloquent - how to join a table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I working on an API for my app.

I'm trying to pull items from the database and return them in JSON object,
my items table looks like this:

```
Items
-id
-name
-description
-price
-currency_id
-company_id
```

this is how I'm getting the items:

```
$rows = Company::where('guid',$guid)
                ->first()
                ->items()
                ->orderBy('name', $sort_order);
```

I want to replace the currency_id with a currency object that contains all the columns of currency table

so my result will be like this:

```
[
  {
    'id':'1',
    'name':'name',
    'description': 'example',
    'price':'100',
    'currency':{
     'id':'1',
     'name':'usd',
     'symbol': '$'
     }
  }
]
```

**update**:
This is my currencies table:

```
id
name
symbol
code
```

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27047832/386579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit 2: The user's problem was more complex than this since there was pagination and search integration with the query. Helped with https://pastebin.com/ppRH3eyx

Edit : I've tested the code. So here.

In Company model

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
}
```

In Item model

```
public function currency()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Currency::class);
}
```

Controller logic

```
$items = Company::with(['items' => function($query) use ($sort_order) {
    $query->with('currency')->orderBy('name', $sort_order);
}])
    ->where('guid', $guid)
    ->first()
    ->items;
```

Result with test data

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Toy",
        "description": "Random text 2",
        "price": 150,
        "company_id": 1,
        "currency_id": 1,
        "currency": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "usd",
            "symbol": "$",
            "code": "USD"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Phone",
        "description": "Random text",
        "price": 100,
        "company_id": 1,
        "currency_id": 1,
        "currency": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "usd",
            "symbol": "$",
            "code": "USD"
        }
    }
]
```

---

Try this.

```
$rows = Company::with('items.currency')
    ->where('guid', $guid)
    ->first()
    ->items()
    ->orderBy('name', $sort_order);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Unknown column 'currencies.item_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `currencies` where `currencies`.`item_id`

Comment: Can you post your currency table structure?

Comment: Your relationship posted in the other comment is wrong, change it to `public function currency()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Currency');
    }`

Comment: now I'm not getting the error but still, i don't get the result I need, I want to return an array of items and in that array instead  of returning the currency_id I want to return currency object

Comment: Is the order by field `name` from the items table or from company table? I'll write some test code and get back to you after your response

Comment: i've updated my answer after testing the code. should work, if not you're doing something wrong on your end.

Comment: still not working, i'm getting this results: {"rows":[{"guid":"d2a12dc0-3c70-11e7-b804-4f1bebfb243b","name":"test","description":"test","price":100,"currency_id":2,"company_id":1}]}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144635/discussion-between-sandeesh-and-ilan-finkel).

Answer (score 2):

Try below

Make one relationship  in Item Model

```
 public function currencies() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Currency');
     }
```

then do below in your controller

```
$row=Items::All()->with('currencies');
```

Comment: actually, my relationship is different because each item has only one currency.  public function currency(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Currency');
    }

Comment: and I want to get the items of the company as you can see in my example